# How to convert YUV file format to H264 on the board using G streamer?

Tags: h.264, yuv

I am using different command for convert the .YUV to h264  please guide me regarding this.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.yuv ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)YUY2, width=64, height=32, framerate=\(fraction\)30/1 ! xvimagesink
```

also, i  am trying,

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location= no__.yuv ! legacyh264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

please help me regarding.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Gstreamer_cheat_sheet

For e.g.

```
gst-launch -e filesrc location=test.yuv ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)YUY2, width=64, height=32, framerate=\(fraction\)30/1 ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=test.ts
```

Install x264enc using

```
sudo apt-get install libx264-dev
```